# Error al crear rama GIT

Tags: git, git-push, git-commit

Tengo la estructura de mi Git tal que así

```
.
├── master
├── releases
└───features
    └───releases
        └───team
```

Quiero que en mi rama releases este todo el nuevo codigo para ser aprobado, en la rama features/releases/team estará todo el código nuevo a realizar por mi y mi equipo, y luego, quiero añadir a `features/releases/team` una nueva subrama y que quede asi:

```
.
├── master
├── releases
└───features
    └───releases
        └───team
            └───tests
```

Cuando intento hacer un **git checkout -b features/releases/team/tests** me dice lo siguiente:

`$  git checkout -b features/releases/team/tests fatal: cannot lock ref 'features/releases/team/tests' exists; cannot create 'features/releases/team/tests'`

No tengo mucha experiencia con GIT, qué he hecho mal.

Comment: La respuesta a la pregunta puntual es: estás tratando de crear una rama con un nombre que ya existe en tu repositorio local (es decir, ya tienes una rama llamada `features/releases/team/tests`).

Comment: @eftshift0 si, tests existe pero quiero crear una dentro de test.

Comment: Como comentario adicional: en git no existen "subramas". Solo _ramas_.... y las ramas podrían tener un "upstream".

Comment: Llegados a este punto, creo que vale la pena una respuesta. Dame un par de minutos para escribirla.

Comment: Vale, muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que estás tratando de hacer es imposible dada la forma en la que se guardan las cosas en git. Cuando tu tienes una rama que se llama `features/releases/team`, en git, se crea un **archivo** con esa ruta dentro de `.git/refs/heads` (que es donde se guarda el hash al que apunta dicha rama). Si quisieras crear ahora una rama que se llama `features/releases/team/tests`, sería imposible para git hacerlo ya que `.git/refs/heads/features/releases/team` tendría que ser un **directorio**... pero ya dijimos que es un archivo (por la rama, cierto?).

Creo que bien vale la pena echarle una leída a https://git-scm.com/book/es/v2/Ramificaciones-en-Git-%C2%BFQu%C3%A9-es-una-rama%3F